# CiviReport Max Participants

Tags: civievent, civireport

I currently generate an Event Report of upcoming events that shows how many participants are registered for each event, but I'd also like for it to show the max participants allowed. When looking through the fields available in the Columns tab, I don't see Max Participants or anything like it.

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a field called "capacity" on the event income summary report. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Ah ok, I had started from an Event Participant Report not knowing that different fields are available in different templates. This should work for me though, thanks!